# Monolog not logging context

Tags: symfony, logging, monolog, symfony3.x

In my Symfony 3.4. application I have configured a custom logger:

```
monolog:
  handlers:
    my_channel:
      level: debug
      type: stream
      path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/my_channel.log'
      max_files: 10
      channels: [my_channel]
```

When I use this logger in my Code which I have injected correctly with the channel "my_channel".

```
 $this->logger->error('error message', $data = ['my context here']);
```

On the screen I get $data info correctly shown:

```
09:00:08 ERROR     [my_channel] error message ["my context here"]
```

but not in my logs the context is empty:

```
09:00:08 ERROR     [my_channel] error message []
```

**Question**: How can I log the context to my log files too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason was that the context data was not UTF-8 encoded.